# jQuery popover with Jquery Datatable at row level

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap, popover

I am using jQuery Datatables to show data in my table but want a popover with more info on every row.

**Where am i**

I have been able to get data in my table using jQuery datatable and can get popover at every row.

**Problem**
I only want one popover to display at a time, whats happening is, i have a code where onClick of row, i get popover and when user clicks another row, i get another popover against that row. As i want user to go through all the popover data and user to also click on a link on popover, i cant keep popover `'trigger' : 'hover'` and this doesnt allow user to read/click all the data on popover but if i use manual, it doesnt close automatically on opening on another popover on that page.

i have tried something like `$('#tableid tbody tr').popover('hide');` (thinking this will hide every popover associated with tr) before opening a popover but this doesnt work or rather stops popovers to open atall.

js i am trying to use to show popovers

`$('#tableid  tbody tr').live('click', function () {
        if (this.id.length > 0) {`

```
        //$('#tableid tbody tr').popover('hide');
        $(this).popover({
            //'trigger' : 'manual',
            'container': 'body',
            'placement': 'right',
            'title': 'Another Test',
            'content': 'Test'
        }).popover('show');           
    }
});
```

Can anyone guide me in right direction to sort this out.

Any help will be appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: can you post the html and whatever js you've wrote so far ?

Comment: @Jay Can you make a fiddle and/or edit your post?

Comment: Very well! :) And is `popover` is generated by some kinda plugin?

Comment: @SachinG : `popover` is created by bootstrap plugin

Answer (score 1):

You can use code like this to hide any other popovers that are open..

```
$('[data-toggle=popover]').on('click', function (e) {
   $('[data-toggle=popover]').not(this).popover('hide');
});
```

The `[data-toggle=popover]` selector can be modified accordingly for however you're creating popovers for each TR.

### [**Demo**](http://bootply.com/61233)

Comment: Problem i have is as my table rows are created dynamically on a fly, i need to attach click event to every row using .live parameter. when i am using your .not(this) code, i can only get first popover (irrespective of which row i click) after that no popover opens up on any row.

Comment: You shouldn't need to use .live -- .on is the preferred method.

Comment: Thanks @Skelly, i have changed my code so that, i only show popover on hovering and click event has been added at row level. Thanks for creating that demo, will come to use to someone.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use :

```
 $('[data-toggle=popover]').popover({

    trigger:"click"

});

$('[data-toggle=popover]').on('click', function (e) {

    $('[data-toggle=popover]').not(this).popover('hide');

});
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use this method as i tried this all time whenever i need to toggle popover in every cell

```
$('#viewtable tbody').on('click', 'tr',  function () {
    $("#viewtable tbody tr").removeClass('row_selected');       
    $(this).addClass('row_selected');
    var tr = $(this).closest('tr');
    var selectedData = jDataTable.row(tr).data();
    console.log(selectedData);

    var dataaa = JSON.stringify(selectedData);
    var cont = '<div class="text-center" id="viewdiv"><button class="btn btn-warning" ng-click="viewticketdetails('+selectedData.ticketid+')"\>View Ticket</button><button class="btn btn-info" ng-click="updateticket()">Update Ticket</button></div>';                   

    $(this).popover({
        html: true,
        sanitize: false,
        trigger: 'click',
        placement: 'auto top',
        content : function(){
            return compile(cont)(scope);
        }
    }).popover('toggle');

    $('#viewtable tbody tr').off('click').on('click', function() {
    });
});
```

hopefully this will help you out .. let me know if this  will help you